# CSS feature detection in SVG

Tags: css, svg

I'm building SVG infographics using `:hover`, `:active`, and `:focus` to add a layer of interactivity to enhance it. The graphic works fine as rendered statically as an <IMG>, but when it gets placed inline or as an <OBJECT>, it is enhanced ([example SVG](https://cdn.statically.io/gist/alexmwalker/effdec2b65297ac9957c6064f70e35d1/raw/6a9ec9d55d16e86f370bd33cb1de26d96c4246bd/Interactive-color-wheel.svg)).

If *possible*, I'd love the graphic to display an 'interactive' label – that doesn't appear when the SVG is rendered in an <IMG> tag. No scripts. Independent of environment. Essentially I'm trying to do 'CSS feature detection'.

My approach was to set a base CSS rule:

```
.red {
    fill: red;
   }
```

Add a rule for the `:hover` state for the whole SVG surface.

```
svg:hover .red {
    fill: cyan
   }
```

Inline and <OBJECT> SVGs honor that rule. IMG-based SVGs ignore it. As they should. Perfect.

The trick (I thought...) was to set up a `:not(:hover)` state. When the SVG ***ISN'T*** hovered over, do this. How would an IMG tag know what is being :not(:hover)ed on, right?

```
svg:not(:hover) .red {
    fill: blue;
   }
```

Sure enough, inline and <OBJECT> SVGs honor this rule and turn the `fill:blue`.

Unfortunately, (and unhelpfully) so does the <IMG> tag version. :-/

I don't understand how the renderer disables `:hover{...}` in <IMG> yet parses it well enough to not break `svg:not(:hover){...}`.

Is what I'm trying to do impossible?

This is a CodePen demos for clarification:

https://codepen.io/alexmwalker/pen/BaoBdqL

Comment: I don’t think it “disables `:hover{...}`”, not in any way like this would get ignored when parsing the styles, or anything like that. The hover _event_ simply is not triggered for any of the SVG content, when embedded via `<img>`. And if no event is triggered, then of course `svg:not(:hover)` applies all the time, same as just `svg` on its own would have to begin with.

Comment: So you're saying that i could write `svg:not(:doublebackflip){...}` and because the event is never triggered, the rule gets honored?

Comment: If `:doublebackflip` as an invalid pseudo class doesn’t trigger a parse error … but yes, in theory. There’s no difference to `foo:not(.someclass)` – that works on all `foo` elements, that don’t have the class `someclass`. “The event of” that element having that class never triggers here, if you’d want to phrase it that way, so … same thing.

Comment: Yep, that makes sense. Good explanation. Cheers. I don't think there's a way around this one sans JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest would be to use javascript to set a particular class on the root element. Scripts, are not executed from an `<img>`, just like they don't emit user-inputs to the loaded svg document:

```js
const content = `
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
    <style>
      :root.has-user-input rect {
        fill: green;
      }
    </style>
    <rect fill="red" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50"/>
    <script>
      document.documentElement.classList.add('has-user-input');
    <\/script>
  </svg>`;
const blob = new Blob([content], { type: "image/svg+xml" });
const url = URL.createObjectURL( blob );

img.src = object.data = url;
```

```html
<img id="img">
<object id="object"></object>
```

Comment: That might end up being my only approach, but I've been trying to avoid JS if possible as there's always a risk SVG image uploaders sanitize it. They seem to leave CSS alone.

Comment: Only other solution I can think of would be to serve your image with different *fragment-URLs* (`url.svg#element`) You can then abuse the `:target` pseudo selector, as demonstrated here: https://gist.github.com/LeaVerou/5198257, but js is probably more scalable.

Comment: I guess if the JS is adding the 'Interactive' label to the OBJECT/inline versions, the worst case scenario – i.e the script gets stripped out somewhere along the line – isn't such a horrible UX.  I appreciate your thoughts. Thanks!